# display only fixed no of items in Recycler view and remaining items in new page(using Show all)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i have 100 items which is parsed from a JSON file.
i want to display 20 items in a recycler(horizontal scroll) and on reaching the 20th item i want to add a footer that shows a "Show ALL"(imagebutton) which when clicked goes to a new page where you can view all the 100 items in a grid view//
,my doubt is how can i just display only 20 items out of the 100 items in the first page.

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter inside `getItemCount()` method just return your wanted number of items:

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 20; //20 items will be displayed
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped, if this solved your problem please accept the answer so other developers with the same problem could use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the size of the adapter 20.when you click show more then move to next page and show all data.